# Is a list between two other lists

Tags: python, math

Every element of the list:

```
[16,15,14,13,12,11,10]
```

has to be between

```
y =[30,30,25,25,25,20,20] and 
[15,15,12.5,12.5,12.5,10,10] #(half of the first one)
```

In this case the program has to be False because 12 isn't the same or higher as 12.5.
How can you make a good program, so that in this case the program will give: False?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
a = [16, 15, 14, 13, 12, 11, 10]

y = [30, 30, 25, 25, 25, 20, 20]

print(all([y[i] / 2 <= a[i] <= y[i] for i in range(len(a))]))
```

I hope it helped ;)